# How to select specific two groups from a list of data for t-test and bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to select two groups from data for the t-test and bar plot?
I  have data made of several groups/substrate (i.e., O1, O2, O3, S_O4, S_O5 etc.), and I need to draw a bar plot using specific two group/substrate (e.g., O1 and S_O5) and then run t-test. I need to help. Would you please check the attached link for Excel data?

```
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
library(xlsx)
library(patchwork)
df<-read.xlsx("umar_02.xlsx", header = T, 1)
# Statistical test

######## Figure 1 ########
stat.test <- df %>%
  t_test(Moisture_content ~ substrate) %>%
  add_significance()
stat.test

# Box plots with p-values
bxp1 <- ggboxplot(df, x = "substrate", y = "Moisture_content", fill = "substrate", 
                 palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), width = 0.35)



stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "substrate")
bxp1 + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p = {p}") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.1)))+
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 3
  )
```

Excel data: [enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YZQRihyc5aTWehda8Wr24xwm23a87jv7/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102539758905103985682&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- rio::import("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YZQRihyc5aTWehda8Wr24xwm23a87jv7/edit#gid=1007932109")
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
stat.test <- df %>%
  filter(Ortamlar %in% c("O1", "S_O5")) %>% 
  t_test(Moisture_content ~ Ortamlar) %>%
  add_significance()
stat.test

stat.test
# # A tibble: 1 x 9
#   .y.              group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic    df     p p.signif
# * <chr>            <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
# 1 Moisture_content O1     S_O5       3     3     -2.20  2.50 0.132 ns      

# Box plots with p-values
bxp1 <- df %>%
  filter(Ortamlar %in% c("O1", "S_O5")) %>%
  ggboxplot( x = "Ortamlar", y = "Moisture_content", fill = "Ortamlar", 
                  palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), width = 0.35, xlab = "Substrate")


stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "Ortamlar")
stat.test <- stat.test %>% mutate(y.position=5.15)
bxp1 + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p = {p}") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.1)))+
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 3
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We may need to `filter` with `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
stat.test <- df %>% 
  filter(Ortamlar %in% c("O1", "S_O5")) %>%
  rename(substrate = Ortamlar) %>%
  t_test(Moisture_content ~ substrate) %>%
  add_significance()
```

-output

```
stat.test
# A tibble: 1 x 9
  .y.              group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic    df     p p.signif
* <chr>            <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1 Moisture_content O1     S_O5       3     3     -2.20  2.50 0.132 ns
```

Comment: @DaveArmstrong and akrun many thanks for the help. It works; kind of you